# How loading file in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a file, name: "file1.pl" in c:/.

Now I want to load the file into the [prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable), and then ask a query about the procedure and the relations that I defined.

as I understood, I need to do the next stpes:

1. file -> edit.
2. file -> reload modified files.
3. file -> Navigator to view file and procedre.

When I an doing these steps, Nothing is happen. When I ask the query, It gives me the next problem: `toplevel: Undefined procedure: blabla/2 (DWIN couldnt correct goal)`

Thank you.

Comment: What are the contents of your file? What is your query?

Comment: @liori, The file containes all the realtion, and the procedure blabla. my query is: ?- blabla(Customer,Product).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing `consult(filename)`.  Extension might or might not be needed.

Comment: In SWI-Prolog (Mac) you need to put the path within quotes, like so: `consult('~/path/to/file/myFile')` where `myFile.pl` is your Prolog code file.